# Protractor for Angular 2 - clicking on a d3/c3 class

Tags: angular, d3.js, protractor, c3.js

I am writing test cases for an Angular 2 app, the problem is that I need to click on a bar to go to another page:

```
it('should drill down when I click on the bar', (done) => {
  element.all(by.css(".c3-event-rect-3")).then(function (elements) {
    elements[0].click().then(function() {
      expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('some url piece to add up the current');
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

It seems like Protractor cannot click on the bar since the class is a d3/c3 class. I can click on the bar manually and it works just fine. Anyone has a solution to this yet? (I use d3 v3 )

edit:

[image]

For the code I can say current URL is localhost:4200 and for example where I want it to go after I click a chart is: localhost:4200/table/1.

Comment: `c3.js` "fades in" the bars on render, are you sure the bar is even there before you "click" on it?

Comment: @Mark pretty sure, I can see on the developer tools/debugger

Comment: You can see what on the developer tools/debugger?  That `by.css(".c3-event-rect-3")` returns the `rect` you are looking for?

Comment: @Mark It does, I have no problem finding that bar via protractor, if you look at the code above; it fails on the 3rd line if that code

Comment: Can you share page `URL` or `HTML` source of target element?

Comment: @Andersson It doesn't have a URL yet it is localhost but I edited, I hope this is what you were asking for?

Comment: and by `cannot click` you mean that nothing happens or you get exception?

Comment: @Andersson Like it knows what the class is but it doesn't fire the click event so the test fails, exception is like:

`Expected 'http://localhost:4200/ to contain '/table/1'.
Expected :"/table/1/"
Actual   :"http://localhost:4200"`